# Call a touch function using NGUI/Unity3D?

Tags: android, touch, unity-game-engine, ngui

I have a game that is using GUITextures for buttons but it isn't working on different resoltutions.  So I was told NGUI would do it very easily.  But I already have the code written for the GUITexture buttons.

How do I do it for NGUI buttons using the same textures?  I've searched everywhere and can not find any answers....the NGUI forums are not much help.

Comment: Do I just declare the button as a GameObject instead of a GUITexture and keep it the way I have it???

Comment: Did you create a global GameObject in your main script? Something like `public GameObject yourGameObjName;`?

Comment: Yes I tried that.  But the touch code didn't work for it.

Comment: @Dasu,  NGUI texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gameobject should have any type of collider component then in script do the following:

```
//Use UIEventListener to bind your gameobject with your desired method 

public GameObject YOUR_BUTTON_GAMEOBJECT;

UIEventListener.Get(YOUR_BUTTON_GAMEOBJECT).onClick += YOUR_METHOD_NAME;


//METHOD SIGNATURES 
void YOUR_METHOD_NAME(GameObject gameObject){
     //On Click Stuff
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this this evening.  I am getting some bad response times with it.  Also I am using a itween animation on the button and it is scaling 1000% times bigger then the -.4 it is suppose to.

Comment: Where does the UIEventListener go?

Comment: you can put that UIEventListener statement in Start() method. So whenever your gameobject instantiated it starts listening to onclick event.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works perfectly.  Besides the tweens for ngui I like it so far.   Would it be possible to use itween instead of the tween ngui has??